# is there any way to prevent some actions from recording in macros?

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I'm working on coreldraw and i need to record macro but i found that while i'm recording the macro if i zoom in and out it recording that as you see in the code :

```
Sub Macro1()
' Recorded 20/10/2020
Dim s1 As Shape
Set s1 = ActiveLayer.CreateRectangle(1.182217, 8.734961, 5.822764, 1.853063)
s1.Rectangle.CornerType = cdrCornerTypeRound
s1.Rectangle.RelativeCornerScaling = True
s1.Fill.ApplyNoFill
s1.Outline.SetPropertiesEx 0.007874, OutlineStyles(0), CreateCMYKColor(0, 0, 0, 100), ArrowHeads(0), ArrowHeads(0), cdrFalse, cdrFalse, cdrOutlineButtLineCaps, cdrOutlineMiterLineJoin, 0#, 100, MiterLimit:=5#, Justification:=cdrOutlineJustificationMiddle
Dim s2 As Shape
Set s2 = ActiveLayer.CreateRectangle(1.939858, 8.166728, 5.096693, 2.515996)
s2.Rectangle.CornerType = cdrCornerTypeRound
s2.Rectangle.RelativeCornerScaling = True
s2.Fill.ApplyNoFill
s2.Outline.SetPropertiesEx 0.007874, OutlineStyles(0), CreateCMYKColor(0, 0, 0, 100), ArrowHeads(0), ArrowHeads(0), cdrFalse, cdrFalse, cdrOutlineButtLineCaps, cdrOutlineMiterLineJoin, 0#, 100, MiterLimit:=5#, Justification:=cdrOutlineJustificationMiddle
Dim s3 As Shape
Set s3 = ActiveLayer.CreateRectangle(2.444953, 7.661638, 4.623169, 3.021091)
s3.Rectangle.CornerType = cdrCornerTypeRound
s3.Rectangle.RelativeCornerScaling = True
s3.Fill.ApplyNoFill
s3.Outline.SetPropertiesEx 0.007874, OutlineStyles(0), CreateCMYKColor(0, 0, 0, 100), ArrowHeads(0), ArrowHeads(0), cdrFalse, cdrFalse, cdrOutlineButtLineCaps, cdrOutlineMiterLineJoin, 0#, 100, MiterLimit:=5#, Justification:=cdrOutlineJustificationMiddle
Dim s4 As Shape
Set s4 = ActiveLayer.CreateRectangle(2.792205, 7.314386, 4.244346, 3.368343)
s4.Rectangle.CornerType = cdrCornerTypeRound
s4.Rectangle.RelativeCornerScaling = True
s4.Fill.ApplyNoFill
s4.Outline.SetPropertiesEx 0.007874, OutlineStyles(0), CreateCMYKColor(0, 0, 0, 100), ArrowHeads(0), ArrowHeads(0), cdrFalse, cdrFalse, cdrOutlineButtLineCaps, cdrOutlineMiterLineJoin, 0#, 100, MiterLimit:=5#, Justification:=cdrOutlineJustificationMiddle
s1.Move 2.083512, -2.272921
ActiveDocument.Undo
Windows.FindWindow("test.cdr*").ActiveView.SetViewPoint 3.423571, 8.040457, 16
Windows.FindWindow("test.cdr*").ActiveView.SetViewPoint 5.623571, 9.240457, 31
ActiveDocument.AddToSelection s2, s3
Dim s5 As Shape
Set s5 = ActiveSelection.Group
End Sub
```

this commands are responsible for that :

```
Windows.FindWindow("test.cdr*").ActiveView.SetViewPoint 3.423571, 8.040457, 16
Windows.FindWindow("test.cdr*").ActiveView.SetViewPoint 5.623571, 9.240457, 31
```

So when I run the macro in another document, it fails

is there any way to prevent this actions from recording or generally to solve this problem ?

Comment: `or generally to solve this problem` - delete them afterwards.

Comment: how can i delete them ?

Comment: select the text and erase the text. You can also add the superior comma character `'` at the beginning of the line that will turn line's the text green meaning that the row is a comment, meaning that is pure text for a person to read not having any impact in the code execution

Comment: but i need that automatically , i don't want to open the code and edit it manually .
the script that i am working on recording many macros and from different persons